# use shared library with eclipse on windows

Tags: c, eclipse-cdt, dynamic-library

On Windows 10, using eclipse for c projects I have installed the MinGW compiler.  I've been able to add a static library (*.h, *.c files).  I can't for some reason get a shared library to work.

I notice that for my shared library I generate a *.o file and a *.dll file but I am not creating a *.so file.

Here are the steps I'm taking:

```
1) open eclipse in new workspace
2) create a new c project
    a) project name ->SharedLib
    b) project type -> shared Library -> empty project
    c) toolchain -> MinGW GCC
3) In SharedLib folder 
    a) create test.h (header file) and test.c (source file)

    test.h

    #ifndef TEST_H_
    #define TEST_H_
    void test_print(void);
    #endif /* TEST_H_ */

    test.c

    #include <stdio.h>
    void test_print(void){
    printf("we have lift off");
    }
4) build Sharedlib
    a) creates Binaries -> libSharedLib.dll
5) create new c project Exec
    a) empty project
    b) add source file main.c

    main.c

    #include <stdio.h>
    #include "test.h"
    int main(void){
        printf("we are on the launch pad");
        test_print();
    }
6) go into properties of Exec->Paths and Symbols->references
   a) choose SharedLib, apply and close

7) build all and then run
```

I have no error messages and no output. the only thing it says is:

```
<terminated>(exit value: -1,073,741,515)Exec.exe[C/C++ Application]
D:\workplace3\Exec\Debug\Exec.exe(9/14/23,3:05pm)
```

Could really use some help getting this to work.

The goal is to get this shared library automatically included in all my c projects

Comment: Do you want to use `function` in `libSharedLib.dll`?

Comment: .so is a Unix thing, Windows has .dll. Your exit code means "some DLL was not found". You need to either place your .dll file next to your .exe file (in the same directory) or place it somewhere in the %PATH%.